# jQuery Ajax request is only working with one parameter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xampp

i have a problem using ajax with a php file.

Used Code:

```
function deleteImage() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : '../includes/deleteImage.php',
        contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data : {
            method : "deleteImage",
            id : "1"
        },
        success : function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        },

        failure : function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });

}
```

It doesn't work and the Chrome Console is showing me the following error:

```
GET http://localhost/MyPage/WebContent/includes/deleteImage.php?method=deleteImage&id=1
```

Okay, it looks like a missing file.
But when leaving the id parameter out, the request works without a problem.

I tried with different parameter names and with a plain xmlhttprequest without jquery.

The same error code is shown like above.

An other request with the same structure is working without a problem.
(`http://localhost/MyPage/WebContent/includes/jsListener.php?method=showMainSiteEditor&id=4`)

My local server is XAMPP and i'm testing in Google Chrome.

Comment: What error? You just showed a normal GET request.

Comment: I think you are missing the second part of the error message.

Comment: can you show the content of deleteImage.php? so that I can help you much better.

Comment: Can you share the: deleteImage.php code. So that we can check it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code working perfect on my end with both post and get method try to give full url in method

```
function deleteImage() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
       url: "includes/ajax_response.php",
        contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data : {
            method : "deleteImage",
            id : "1"
        },
        success : function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
            console.log(msg);
        },

        failure : function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });

}
```

and ajax_response.php

```
if($_REQUEST['method']=='deleteImage')
{
echo $_REQUEST['method'].$_REQUEST['id'];
}
```

Comment: I failed really hard in my deleteImage.php file. I did the wrong brackets in my GET method in the php file. But i thought it there is not mistake in the php file because of the GET error code... :(

Answer (score 1):

Please can you share error message and deleteImage.php code

still you can try some like:

pass direct data string

```
data :'method=deleteImage&id=1'
```

instead of

```
data : {
            method : "deleteImage",
            id : "1"
}
```

and use full URL too.